# Cannot get program to jump (gdb)

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

```
   0x0003e2d2 <+80>:    cmpl   $0x0,-0xc(%eax)
   0x0003e2d6 <+84>:    je     0x3e334
```

I have tried changing the je opcode to jne, jg, and jl and still cannot get it to jump to 0x3e334. I was thinking about playing around with the registers but I'm not too sure where to start with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not change it to `jmp`? `jne` should have worked too, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- with the original code try changing the zero flag ZF to 1
- patch je to jmp

both should work fine, but the Zero flag will only work once